# call django consumer using signals

Tags: django-channels

Is there a way to call a consumer by post_save signal?
that's my consumer and i don't know how to call it, what should i put in the parameters of it?
in models:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def SendMessage(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    consumer = ChatConsumer(room_id=instance.receiver.pk)
    ChatConsumer.receive(self=consumer, pk=instance.pk)
```

my consumer:

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['pk']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_id

        # Join room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
    
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
    # Receive message from web socket
    async def receive(self, pk):
        pk = pk
        print(pk)
        self.room_id = pk
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_id

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'pk': pk,
            }
        )
    
    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        pk = event['pk']



        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'pk': pk
        }))
```

when i try this, i get this error:
object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Comment: In the documentation their is a way to use consumers outside of consumers https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers; from my understanding you want to broadcast a message after a particular message is saved in the database.

Comment: @ChinmayDali i changed it to this ~ @receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def SendMessage(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pk = instance.pk
    room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % pk
    channel_layer.group_send(
        room_group_name,
        {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'pk': pk,
            }
    ) ~ but nothing happens

Comment: share your code of django-signals and models.py so that it can be easier figure out.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still looking, I solved it here's my consumers full code

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async, async_to_sync
from django.db.models.signals import *
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Message 
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['pk']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_id

        # Join room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
    
    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message_pk = event["message_pk"]
        print("received" + str(message_pk))


        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'pk': message_pk}))
        


@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def SendMessage(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pk = instance.receiver.pk
    message_pk = instance.pk
    room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % pk
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        room_group_name,
        {'type': 'chat_message','message_pk': message_pk,})
```